# Feedback for personal brand facelift

Tags: logo, typography, critique, branding, kerning

I'm a multimedia designer and my personal brand is turning 20 years.
[image: Before the facelift]

I wanted to make a facelift to my current logo by dropping the word 'multimedia' and changing the brand color. I switched the font from **Century Gothic** to **Avenir Book**. I believe this font brings more harmony to the composition. Since I'm from Argentina, the brand color is now tied to the [colors of our flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Argentina).

[image: After the facelift]

I would be glad to read your thoughts and feedback:

1. Are proportions and kerning correctly applied?
2. Do you think the brand color change is a smart move?

Other comments will also be welcome.

Comment: Here is a comment: If you google "sonix" you get a lot of "anything". So if you drop "multimedia" I suppose you have used those 20 years to establish yourself - or you want to use new areas where you write the blurb of who you are and what you do.

You are now one of the brands where neither the word nor the logo is telling anything about "product" or "services". Works for the big guys like Google and Toyota, so I wish you luck that it will work for you.

Comment: I see your point. I made a version with the word 'multimedia' -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/9k4syqa0jplxd4f/after_review_with_multimedia.png?dl=0. I believe, however, that the brand should work in context. Context also tells what the brand does and also reflects other corporate things. I've heard once that the logo of a toy factory shouldn't necessarily convey a childish image.

Answer (score 4):

Personal opinion....

I dislike the thinner font weight. The more open counters are nice, but the thinner stroke weights are contrary to the mark. Kerning is better in the thin type, especially surrounding the "o" and "g". But I'd still prefer a thicker face if it were my brand.

In addition, the left angle of the mark's "A" has a "bump" in it. It's not quite straight and it's not quite a curve. It's like a magnet for my eye. A more defined curve or straightening out that stroke may serve the brand better. Also, if it were my art, I'd ensure the ring around the mark is the same thickness as the strokes in the type.

Comment: I previously tried with thicker strokes and I perceived it to be a little bit too agressive (it might be due to the length of the word). The stroke size is, indeed, the same as the ring. I'll play around with the A a little bit more.

Comment: Here's a first iteration using Avenir Heavy: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8fqwzx4afezrm3j/argensonix_logo_variants.png?dl=0 I believe that switching to lighter strokes provides slightly better harmony.

Answer (score 3):

20 years!

This is a very personal opinion which you are free to consider or not :) After using these ultra classic font families myself for a long time, I'm now moving away from these and trying out the new wave of font design.

There's alot of crazy fonts out there and these could potentially work for a multimedia business. Also, moving from black to blue is a good idea, again because multimedia is about motion and color so why not. But then again, why not go for a gradient fill which you can also animate in your reels and so on. Just some ideas! :)

Then, if you really need to stick to Avenir, at least make it bolder.

[image]

Comment: Gradients could play well in later iterations. Given the thinner strokes of the font, it could be wiser to play with background animations.